# User Interaction Enabled in the Attribute inspector or in the controller code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently developing a iOS project and I was wondering what is the difference between checking "User Interaction Enabled" in the attribute inspector or setting ".userInteractionEnabled" to "true", is it a matter of best practices, does it even matter at all?

Thanks in advance guys,

Mathias

Comment: In additional to @David right answer, you can use IBInspectable / IBDesignable keywords to add your custom class basic properties to interface builder, and setting up them in interface builder, not in code. Check link if you interested http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Answer (score 4):

There is no functional difference.

It basically comes down to your preference, or the coding guidelines that are already in place in a project.
As general advice, avoid mixing between the two alternatives as much as possible, because it makes code hard to maintain in the long run.

I follow the rule that all static setup is done through IB, and stuff that needs to change during runtime is set in code.